# Is there a way to automatically calculate attribute values for new features?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am creating a vector point layer which will be added to over time.  I have been using the field calculator to populate fields such as X and Y coordinates.

I'm wondering if there is a way to have QGIS automatically calculate values in the columns for which a new point is created.  Eg. when I put in a new point it automatically fills out the X and Y coordinate fields.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it for a specific data provider? Postgis, Shapefiles, SQLITE etc.?

Comment: For this application it will be Shapefiles that I'm creating.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if your data is stored in a Spatialite DB file or on a PostGIS server, then it's simple to write a trigger that will update columns such as X-Y on each insert of a new feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible in QGIS. If you need this feature, please open a feature request and post the link here.

Answer (score 4):

This feature has been added in QGIS 2.6. Just open the field calculator (from the toolbar or from layer properties "Fields" tab), check "Create virtual field", enter your formula ("$x" and "$y" in your case), and you have an automatically updated field.

Comment: Note that these fields are really virtual. They are not written to the shapefile, so can not be used in another project or software. The field definitions are only written to the project file you are working on.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but it was the first result for my Google search. QGIS 3 has this feature:

[image: Screenshot of layer properties in QGIS 3.28.7, showing default value feature]

You can set a default value for a field value on creation. It can be a static value or a dynamic expression with an option to update when the feature changes.

Comment: But note that it will not update the values when you move the feature.